# Assign HTML snippet to JS variable

Tags: javascript, inserthtml

I have an `example.html` file:

```
<span>
{{test}}
</span>
```

And a `main.js` file:

```
$( "button#test" ).click(function(event) {

        var html = '/example.html';

        //Replaceing {{test}} in example.html with 'Hello, World!' string
        var insertProperty = function (string, propName, propValue) {
            var propToReplace = "{{" + propName + "}}";
            string = string
                .replace(new RegExp(propToReplace, "g"), propValue);
            return string;
        }
        var replacedhtml = insertProperty(html,"test", 'Hello, World!');

        return console.log(replacedhtml);
    });
```

What I currently get in log:

```
/example.html
```

What I expect:

```
<span>
Hello, World!
</span>
```

And there should be a more elegant way to insert property than my `insertProperty` function.

Comment: Writing `var html = '/example.html'` creates a string rather than retrieving the html text from a file. You will need to use `$.ajax` for the latter.

Comment: why don't you use template engines such as ejs, jade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `var html = '/example.html'` creates a string rather than retrieving the html text from a file. Instead, use `$.ajax` to asynchronously request the file and do something with its text.

```js
$('#test').click(function () {

  $.ajax({
    url: '/example.html',
    success: function (html) {

      //Replacing {{test}} in example.html with 'Hello, World!' string
      function insertProperty (string, propName, propValue) {
        return string.replace(new RegExp('{{' + propName + '}}', 'g'), propValue)
      }

      console.log(insertProperty(html, 'test', 'Hello, World!'))
    }
  })

})
```

Comment: Thank, you! This works, but looks more like workaround. I am new to JS, so I can be wrong.